# Iterateing over a list python program

Tags: python

I wanted know how to iterate over a list in my code. I want to get rid of every index value that is equal to 10 and, after completing the program I got an index out of range error. I wanted to know what that means and how could I refine my code so that I get rid of every value that is equal to ten and then return the new list without the 10 values.

Here is my code:

```
mylist = [10,10,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,0,0,0]
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i] ==10:
        mylist.pop(i)


print( mylist)
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you read an introductory Python tutorial: http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Answer (score 0):

An index out of range error is when you are trying to iterate past the amount of items in a data structure. so say you have 3 items in a list if you try access a 4th it will give an index error.

The issue you are having is because you are mutating the list as you iterate over it.

Its generally not a good idea to edit the data you are currently looping over. A better way might be to use a list comprehension like this

```
mylist = [10,10,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,0,0,0]
mylist = [x for x in mylist if x != 10]

>>> mylist
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if your goal is just to eliminate the items with value of  10:

```
>>> mylist = [10,10,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,0,0,0]
>>> [x for x in mylist if x != 10]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Why you are getting Index Out Of Range**: At the start of your program,
>   len(mylist) = 14, but as you remove elements from the list, the length
>   of your list decreases, and you end up accessing index that do not
>   exist.
>
> **How to fix it**: You can try accessing the elements in reverse order and
>   removing 10, as you encounter it.

```
a = [10,10,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,0,0,0]
for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(a))):
    if e == 10:
        a.pop(i)
print a
```